# Showing a norm preserving isomorphism of vector spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Lets define $l^1$ as the complex vector space of all absolutely summable sequences of complex numbers and and $x_0$ consists of all the sequences in $l^\infty$ (all bounded sequences) that eventually tend to 0. Lastly we define $(x_0)^*$ as the set of all continuous linear functionals on the normed space $(x_0, ||.||_\infty)$.

We want to try construct a norm preserving and isomorphic map 
$F:l^1 \rightarrow (x_0)^*$. I haven't practiced many questions like these, so not sure how to start.

Comment: I vaguely recall that $(x_0)^* \cong l^1$ and $(l^1)^* \cong l^\infty$, is one of those what you meant?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, let me edit post. Ben your correct I meant the first one.

Comment: Given $(y_n)$ in $\ell^1$, there is a most natural way to define a linear functional on $\ell^\infty$, so on $c_0$ (the usual notation for $x_0$) in particular: $(x_n)\longmapsto \sum x_ny_n$. This is it: it is your isometric isomorphism from $\ell^1$ onto $c_0^*$. But there is a bit of checking required.

Comment: @julien, thanks let me try prove that is surjective and norm preserving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen the proof constructed explicitly in elsewhere, so hopefully I am not making any mistake.

Any linear operator on $c_{0}$(in your notation $x_{0}$) must satisfy $$f(x)<\infty,|x|_{\infty}=1$$
Since $c_{0}$ constitute all sequences eventually goes to $0$, any $x\in c_{0}$ must be bounded in the $\sup$ norm. So the above essentially implies $$\sum |f(x_{i})|<\infty,x\in c_{0}$$Now, let us define the isomorphism explicitly by $f(e_{i})\rightarrow y_{i}$. Then I claim that the image of $f$, denoted by $y$ must be in $l^{1}$. On the other hand, for any element $y\in l^{1}$, the above identification gives a linear operator on $c_{0}$. This is "obvious" since $c_{0}\in l^{\infty}$.

It remains to prove $y\in l^{1}$. We have to prove every continuous function on $c_{0}$ can be extended to a continuous function on $l^{\infty}$ preserving the norm. But this can be done by Hahn-Banach theorem since $c_{0}$ is a closed linear subspace of $l^{\infty}$. And it is clear that every linear functional on $l^{\infty}$ must be in $l^{1}$ consider the element $(e^{i\theta_{1}},e^{i\theta_{2}},e^{i\theta_{3}},\cdots)$. So we conclude $c_{0}^{*}\cong l^{1}$.

Comment: This is not correct. See [p. 104 here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/ivan.wilde/notes/fa2/fa2.pdf) for a standard argument.

Comment: @julien: May I ask exactly where it is wrong? I am reading the proof on page 107.

Comment: @julien: I see. The proof is much easier than I expected.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, then you want $\sum |f(e_i)|<\infty$ on your second equation. You also want to check that you have an isometry between $\ell^1$ and $c_0^*$. The most natural way is to define it from $\ell^1$ to $c_0^*$. Then to check it is an isometry. And finally that it is surjective.

Comment: @julien: I did not check the isometry part, but I thought the $c_{0}^{*}$ to $l^{1}$ part is correct. Yes, I should have $\sum |f(x_{i})|<\infty$ instead, for $x\in c_{0}$.